# Filter for the datetimes that has gap greater than or equal to a number - R

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a dataframe as follows,

```
ID  date           difference
1   5/1/2016 4:46   NA
2   5/1/2016 4:55   9
3   5/1/2016 5:01   6
4   5/1/2016 5:09   8
5   5/1/2016 5:16   7
6   5/1/2016 5:24   8
7   5/1/2016 5:31   7
8   5/1/2016 5:40   9
9   5/1/2016 5:46   6
10  5/1/2016 5:49   3
11  5/1/2016 5:54   5
12  5/1/2016 5:57   3
13  5/1/2016 6:10   13
```

Here I want to filter for entries that have the time difference greater than or equal to 9. I want to filter two entries before the time difference value is 9 and one entry after that. Basically I want to analyse the trends when the time difference is greater than 9 mins. So I want to take two entries before it and one entry after that, so that I will have 4 entries for each block of time entries to investigate.

I am able to filter it directly with one entry,

```
data %>% filter(difference >= 9)
```

But I want to take two entries before it and one entry after it to investigate. Ideally my output should be like,

```
ID  date           difference
1   5/1/2016 4:46   NA
2   5/1/2016 4:55   9
3   5/1/2016 5:01   6
6   5/1/2016 5:24   8
7   5/1/2016 5:31   7
8   5/1/2016 5:40   9
9   5/1/2016 5:46   6
11  5/1/2016 5:54   5
12  5/1/2016 5:57   3
13  5/1/2016 6:10   13
```

Where whenever the time difference is greater than or equal to 9, I get two before entries and one after entry.

Can anybody give me some idea how to approach this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `shift`, `Reduce` method in `data.table`, suppose `dt` is your data.frame:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
dt[Reduce("|", c(shift(difference >= 9, n = 0:1, type = "lag"), 
                 shift(difference >=9, n = 1:2, type = "lead")))]

          ID date difference
 1: 5/1/2016 4:46         NA
 2: 5/1/2016 4:55          9
 3: 5/1/2016 5:01          6
 4: 5/1/2016 5:24          8
 5: 5/1/2016 5:31          7
 6: 5/1/2016 5:40          9
 7: 5/1/2016 5:46          6
 8: 5/1/2016 5:54          5
 9: 5/1/2016 5:57          3
10: 5/1/2016 6:10         13
```

Comment: Thanks for this one. This works.. But if I want to group by any variable previously and do it recursively, how can I do that?

Comment: for ex, I dont want to fetch the previous days as previous records, so I group it by day, in that case, I would want only entries in a particular cay and I dont want to go to the previous day records. So I group it by day here and then want to do this.

Comment: In that case, you can try `dt[, .SD[Reduce("|", c(shift(difference >= 9, n = 0:1, type = "lag"), shift(difference >=9, n = 1:2, type = "lead")))], by = list(ID)]`. where `ID` is the group variable.

Comment: is ID the variable to be grouped?

Comment: Yes, ID is the group variable.

Answer (score 2):

Note: I used a placeholder series for "date" because it doesn't matter in the context of this code.

There isn't a single-command way of doing what you need, as far as I know. I would suggest doing this with a loop:

```
df <- data.frame(1:13)
df <- cbind(df,2000:2012,c(NA,9,6,8,7,8,7,9,6,3,5,3,13))
colnames(df) <- c("ID","date","difference")

whichAtLeast9 <- which(df$difference >= 9)
wantedRows <- whichAtLeast9

for (i in whichAtLeast9) {
  entries_before <- c(i-1,i-2)
  entries_before <- subset(entries_before,entries_before>0)
  wantedRows <- append(wantedRows,entries_before)
  entries_after <- i+1
  entries_after <- subset(entries_after,entries_after<=13)
  wantedRows <- append(wantedRows,entries_after)
}

# Remove duplicates and sort.
wantedRows <- sort(unique(wantedRows))

finaldf <- df[wantedRows,]
```

Result:

```
> finaldf
   ID date difference
1   1 2000         NA
2   2 2001          9
3   3 2002          6
6   6 2005          8
7   7 2006          7
8   8 2007          9
9   9 2008          6
11 11 2010          5
12 12 2011          3
13 13 2012         13
```